# Easy to use remote PHP app for controlling file permissions?

Tags: permissions, unix

We have a NAS here, in a small company, that I sysadmin (not my full-time job) and my boss want to 
have control on directory access. It's a QNAP so it's Linux-powered.

The NAS doesn't provide an easy way to do it (can't change owner), and changing it in Windows interface is a real pain (need dozens of clicks). He doesn't know CLI so I don't want to tell him how to do it with SSH, too dangerous

So I'm looking for a simple (and open source) web app that we can use to easily administrate this. Do you know any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of PHP application is a real security hazard, so that must be one of the reasons there are not too many of them available (or if there are, I must be blind).

Anyway, [the File Manager module in Webmin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/FileManager) *might* fulfill your needs, though it's a Java applet talking to CGI scripts. Still it should work under QNAP.

Comment: Thanks Janne; file manager module doesn't look easy however. I don't understand the security risk of such app, since people that will edit permission would still authenticate as admin

Comment: Couple of points why that kind of app would be a security nightmare: 1) it requires Apache or other web server run as root 2) if this software is exposed to public Internet (yes, in your case it might not be), a security flaw in software would be a BAD thing